# How to get value from a label in tableviewcell?

Tags: iphone

I have a tableview which contains some text and I have a label inside tableviewcell as subview, in the label there is also some values. My question is, when I tap the cell I want to get the label value, I know how to get a cell value when tapping the cell but I need to get the label value, my code for getting the tablecell value is

```
NSString *localStringValue;
localStringValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
```

and I display it in a textview `textview.text = self.localStringValue;`
My label name is chapterandverse, I need to implement this label instead of `textlabel.text`.
I add `localStringValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].chapterandverse.text;`
but I got error for this code. Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 main ways to do this:

1. You can give the `chapterandverse` label a `tag` value. In Interface Builder, there is a Tag property on the same page where you set the other properties like Text. If you're doing it programmatically, `chapterandverse.tag = 1;`. Then you need to refer to the label by the tag value, like:

   ```
   localStringValue = [(UILabel *)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                                   viewWithTag:1] text];
   ```
2. You can do it by having an `@property` referring to the label in your custom table view cell class. You seem to have already tried to do this, but note that if you call `[cell addSubview:chapterandverse]` that does *not* mean you can later say `cell.chapterandverse`. To make it work properly, you need to make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and add the following declaration to it:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *chapterandverse;
   ```

   And then synthesize it in the cell's `.m` file:

   ```
   @synthesize chapterandverse;
   ```

   Then you can connect the label you placed in Interface Builder to the `chapterandverse` outlet on the view and refer to it by `cell.chapterandverse` like you are doing. If you create it programmatically, though, you will need to initialise the `UILabel` before using it:

   ```
   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
   {
       self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
       if(self != nil)
       {
           CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); // set this properly
           self.chapterandverse = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
           [self.view addSubview:self.chapterandverse];
       }

       return self;
   }
   ```

Comment: @darvidsOn i implement the first method,it works fine,thankyou verymuch.